# When is the analytification of a variety homeomorphic to $\mathbb C$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be the analytification of a variety $V$ such that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.

What can we say about $X$? Can $V$ be singular?

Comment: Yes, of course: the analytification of $\{(z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^2 : z^2 = w^3\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you. If we ask $V$ to be smooth, then $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb A^1$ I think. Is that true?

Comment: Yes to the follow up question, because $\mathbb{A}^1$ can be characterized as the unique nonsingular simply connected  curve which isn't compact.